# Force nuget to ignore package with conflicting target framework

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget

I am working on a Unity3D project. I want to install [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/) nuget package into my class library project. I use command `Install-Package C5 -ProjectName UplusEditorUtils -IgnoreDependencies`. The error I get is:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'C5 2.5.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5', but the 
>   package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package C5 -ProjectName UplusEditorUtils -IgnoreDependencies
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

It seems the package is not compatible with the my project's target framework profile being **.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5**.

I can't change the project's target profile because it will cause other problems and I don't want to get into editing the C5 project either.

Is there a way to tell nuget that my target framework is essentially .Net3.5 or better just ignore the target platform version mismatch altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried what the [github](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/#c5-on-unity3d) page you linked suggests for using C5 with unity, near the bottom of the read.me?

> **C5 on Unity3d**
>
> Open C5.csproj with either Xamarin Studio or MonoDevelop to build C5.dll
> Copy C5.dll into the Asset folder of your project

When building the project make sure to set the target framework to match the one your unity is using (3.5). This works for me.

Another thing you can attempt if you're set on installing it through nuGet is download the package in a seperate C# project that is targeting the correct framework so that nuGet allows you to download it. You then take the downloaded files and copy it over to your Unity project. If the package has functionality not supported you'll have to manually fix those errors though.